# Bullets shooting the wrong way with AddForce

Tags: unity-game-engine, gameobject, rigid-bodies

Im a beginner in unity so right now I'm working in a turn-based game like worms game. But for some reason my attack script only works for the left side units, and not the right side ones. Specifically, the bullets that I instantiate go the wrong way when they are fired for the ones on the right side, but they work exactly as expected for the ones on the left. I have separate scripts for the character buttons but I'm using the same script for the bullets.

Bullet script

```
public float speed;
public float posX, posY;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    rigidbody2D.AddForce (new Vector2 (posX, posY), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
}


// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    //transform.Translate (speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D c){
    if (c.gameObject.tag == "Base") {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        Destroy(c.gameObject);
    }
    else if(c.gameObject.tag == "Player2"){
        Destroy(gameObject);
        Destroy(c.gameObject);
    }
}

void OnBecameInvisible () {
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

Character script

The gameObject go is the prefab of the bullet

```
public GameObject go;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
        if(gameObject.tag == "Player2"){
            if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Backspace)){
                Instantiate(go,transform.position,transform.rotation);
            }
        }

}
```

}

Comment: How you are calculating the `posX` and `posY`? They seem to be the ones setting the direction.

Comment: I had similar problem once. It was due to bullet and the shooter being in the same collision layer. The bullet appeared to be firing in the wrong direction but once i separated the layers it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are applying **the same force** (`posX, posY`) to all of your bullets, so they all go right (correct direction from the left side, opposite direction from the right).

What you need to do is to use a variable to keep track of the direction of each individual gameobject that will fire bullets and use that direction to `AddForce()` to your bullets. Or, if the gameobjects do not move/pass to the other half, you need to differentiate between right and left gameobjects and use corresponding force vectors.